# Handling JSON string after AJAX call in .NET

Tags: jquery, .net, json, ajax, vb.net

I have a jquery post call that sends a request to an aspx page with a json string as an argument. The following is my jquery code:

```
 $.post('saverecords.aspx', { js: JSON.stringify(resultArr) }, function (response) {
                $('#pElement').html(response);
            }, "html");
```

Then in my server side aspx method, I am sending the json string back to the jquery callback method via the .write stream:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request("js"))
    Response.Write(result)
End Sub
```

This returned json string is:

```
 [ { "linename": "ENGINE COMPARTMENT", "answer": "None" }, { "linename": "ENGINE FLUID", "answer": "B" }, { "linename": "BELTS/HOSES", "answer": "B" }, { "linename": "ENG. COMPONENTS", "answer": "B" }, { "linename": "FRONT", "answer": "None" }, { "linename": "HEAD LIGHTS", "answer": "B" }, { "linename": "TURN LIGHTS", "answer": "B" } ]
```

I want to extract the values of the json string into two arrays, linename and answers, either in js in the callback or in a web method in the server using a class(preferably server side).

I tried JSON.Parse in the callback method but for some reason it is not working.

Comment: You could write a class to store the 2 elements together rather than 1980s style parallel arrays.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Is there a reason that you want two separate arrays? Just wondering if that’s a requirement. Also, can you see an error in the browser developer tools console as to why JSON.parse() isn’t working? Make sure parse is all lowercase. If you can get JSON.parse() working, then use jQuery.map() (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ ) to extract all linename properties into one array and answers into another array.

Comment: @iCode It is not a requirement to have 2 arrays as long as i can access the values. If you take a look at my json string you will see that it has an array of key-value pairs - linename and answer. As long as i can get the corresponding value (aka answer) of the linename (key) that is fine. I got it to work on the server side using classes but I was wondering why it doesnt work with js with json.parse. The error was  "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data" so i am sure it is a bad json structure.